# An expected error while running a Markov Chain

Tags: python

While I was running a Markov Chain in Python, I got an error which I had seen for the first time and I didn't know what it meant and what all should I do to fix this error.

My Code

```
import random as r
print ('Hello to my text generator')
print ('This will generate text from the data which you enter')
#author = input("What is the Author's name? >> ")
#title = input("What is the name of this story? >>")
data = "A short story is a piece of prose fiction that typically can be read in one sitting and focuses on a self-contained incident or series of linked incidents, with the intent of evoking a single effect or mood.The short story is a crafted form in its own right. Short stories make use of plot, resonance, and other dynamic components as in a novel, but typically to a lesser degree. While the short story is largely distinct from the novel or novella/short novel, authors generally draw from a common pool of literary techniques.Short story writers may define their works as part of the artistic and personal expression of the form. They may also attempt to resist categorization by genre and fixed formation.Short stories have deep roots and the power of short fiction has been recognized in modern society for hundreds of years.As William Boyd, the award-winning British author and short story writer has said:seem to answer something very deep in our nature as if, for the duration of its telling, something special has been created, some essence of our experience extrapolated, some temporary sense has been made of our common, turbulent journey towards the grave and oblivion.[1]In terms of length, word count is typically anywhere from for short stories, however some have words and are still classed as short stories. Stories of fewer than words are sometimes referred to as short short stories, or flash fiction  Hello"
order = int(input("What should the order be? >> "))
length = int(input('How long should this "story" be? >> '))
class MarkovAlgorithm:
    def __init__(self, order):
        self.order = order
        self.graph = {}
        self.text = None
        return
    def train(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.text= self.text.split()
        for i in range(0, (len(self.text) - self.order + 1)):
            word = tuple(self.text[i: i+self.order])
            nextWord = self.text[self.order]
            if nextWord in self.graph:
                self.graph[word].append(nextWord)
            else:
                self.graph[word] = nextWord
    def generate(self, length):
        index = r.randint(0, len(self.text) - self.order)
        startingWords = self.text[index: index+self.order]
        for i in range(length):
            orginalState = tuple(startingWords[len(startingWords) - self.order:])
            newWord = r.choice(self.graph[orginalState])
            startingWords.append(newWord)
            var = i + 3
        return ''.join(startingWords[self.order:])

text = MarkovAlgorithm(order)
text.train(data)
result = text.generate(length)
#print ("Viola! Our bot created a story from ",title, " by ",author)
print (result)
```

The error I was getting in my IDLE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\-------", line 37, in <module>
    result = text.generate(length)
  File "C:\-------", line 30, in generate
    newWord = r.choice(self.graph[orginalState])
KeyError: ('society', 'for', 's')
```

If someone knows, what this error means and how should I fix this, please tell.

Comment: `originalState` is a `tuple` and you are trying to use that as an index in the array which I don't think you can do.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp If I remove the tuple, then it displays unhashable error. BTW, the video which I was referring to, used a tuple